# Testflight invitation not sent

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight, apple-developer

I have been developing iOS apps for more than 3 years now. One of my clients installed the app via TestFlight in early 2021 on his iPhone. Now that he has changed his phone, I tried to add him to the TestFlight app again, but he didn't receive the invitation or couldn't install the app. In TestFlight, it is displaying that he installed the app version in early 2021 on his old iPhone.

I think for the new iPhone, he needs to accept the invitation, but there is no way to send an invitation to the TestFlight app. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: If he has accepted the TestFlight invitation previously and is still using the same Apple ID then he can simply go into the TestFlight app and find the app as long as the email you originally sent the invitation to has access to the app

Comment: yes that's the normal behavior, but unfortunately he couldn't get the build

Answer (score 0):

Every app bundles have 90 days expiration time. After 90 days you have to upload new bundle version. Otherwise your clients can not download your app. Please check your bundle expire date on testFlight tab of your app on appstoreconnect.apple.com.

[image]

In addition, you can remove your client from internal and external tester on testFlight and add again them to your tester groups.